# AppActivate does not allow to search by word

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an application on my Windows that the window name is something like this: a random number followed by space and after that comes the name of it RECFED. For example "3894 RECFED".

I would like to send a key to that window but I can do that with `AppActivate` cause I can't know the exactly title of the window. I am using something like this

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$wshell.AppActivate("RECFED")
$wshell.SendKeys('a')
```

The code above works if I place the exact name of the window at `AppActivate` but I don't have the exact name in hand all the time.

Comment: because **"SendKeys() is a terrible (flaky, unreliable) automation approach"**

Comment: EVEN though it's terrible I NEED IT @EBGreen. I already got your point, but I need this function no matter what you say.

Comment: You can't just replace a question with a new one; the system limitations are there for a reason, and are not to be bypassed like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-Process` to identify a process by its window title, then use that process's PID for bringing the window to the foreground:

```
$id = Get-Process |
      Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like '*RECFED*' } |
      Select-Object -First 1 -Expand Id

$wshell.AppActivate($id)
```

With that said, be warned that `SendKeys()` is a *terrible* (flaky, unreliable) automation approach, that should only be used as an absolute last resort when *everything* else has failed.

Comment: **absolute last resort when everything else has failed.** - Up to and including simply setting fire to the computer.

Comment: I really need to fire a key cause I dont have control over that RECFED application :(